# Conflicto instalación entity framework core?

Tags: visual-studio, reactjs, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Instalé visual studio 2017 hace poco en mi equipo para crear mi primera aplicación asp.net core con React.

Luego de generar el proyecto, deseo instalar entity framework desde nuget package
con las lineas:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Version 2.2.1
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden observar, hay un conflicto de versiones de algún tipo el cual no se como resolver.
Alguna idea de como arreglar el inconveniente y poder instalar entityframework?

Answer (score 1):

No se si sea lo indicado pero yo resolví este problema agregando al **csproj** los paquetes uno por uno.

Por ejemplo, agregué:

```
> <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore"
> Version="3.1.0"/>
```

Después intenté instalar y me pidió que agregara otro paquete, así los fui agregando uno por uno hasta que ya instaló sin problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que puedo ver estas usando el *TargetFramework* netcoreapp2.1. Puedes revisarlo verificando el archivo del proyecto (.csproj)`<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>` y segun la  el error debes insalar una version mayor o igual que la 2.1.1 y menor que la 2.2.0.

Por lo que te debería funcionar si utilizas una versión entre esas.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Version 2.1.1
```

Se [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/3.0.0-preview.19074.3) las versiones en ese rango son 
2.1.4
2.1.3
2.1.2
2.1.1